# Is $a \sin x + b \sin y \leq \sin(ax + by)$ true?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality

Studying math essay exam, I saw the following strange formula
$$ a \sin x + b \sin y \leq \sin(ax + by), $$
where $x, y$ are arbitrary angles and $a + b = 1.$

Is the above inequality true, and can it be proved?

Comment: Expand $sin(ax+by)$ and see what you get; I am assuming  you know the formula for $Sin(A+B)$

Comment: @user1314: That's not going to help much. How are you going to get $a$ and $b$ outside of the sine functions? This has to do with concavity (someone will surely write up a nice answer shortly).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128888/how-to-show-sin-tx1-ty-leq-t-sin-x1-t-sin-y-where-0-leq-t-leq-1?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

**False** if $x$ and $y$ are really arbitrary. Consider $a=b=\frac12$ and $x=0$ and $y=3\pi$:

\begin{align}
a\sin x+b\sin y&=\frac12 \sin(3\pi) = 0 \\
\sin(ax+by) &= \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)  = -1
\end{align}

It is true if you restrict to the concave region of sine (e.g. $0\le x,y\le\pi$) and $a,b\ge0$, which it is a special case of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: And also require that $a \ge 0$, $b \ge 0$.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Right, thanks. Added it.